# The poison value and undefined value in LLVM

Tags: compiler-errors, llvm, compiler-optimization, undef

LLVM introduces the concept of "poison value", which I never feel sure  to understand.  For example, for the statement

```
%add = add nsw i32 %x, 1
```

If `%x+1` is strictly larger than the largest i32 integer, an arbitrary value is to be assigned to %add. Is that correct to claim that the statement above, i.e.   `%add = add nsw i32 %x, 1`,  can be  semantically described as:

```
if (%x+1) overflows then %add = undef else %add = add i32 %x,1
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they should be semantically equivalent. It is useful to think in terms of C/C++ when looking at LLVM IR instructions that can result in undefined values.

Signed integer overflow results in undefined behavior according to the C/C++ standards, and Clang takes an approximation by mapping the undefined behavior to poison values.

Chris Lattner wrote a [series of blog posts](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) describing how undefined behavior is handled in LLVM and how it can be used for optimization.

UPDATE: There is a new proposal to remove undef and only use poison. You can find a talk on this proposal online at [2016 LLVM Developers’ Meeting: N. Lopes "Undefined Behavior: Long Live Poison!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-3Iiads1EM.)